# Show proxy settings of other user profile

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, proxy

I'm trying to find a command-line to show, list or view proxy settings of another user profile in some computer. I can view my own proxy settings via command-line querying HKCU\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\INTERNET SETTINGS, but this result show only my proxy settings.

There is a way?

Comment: PowerShell's `Invoke-Command -computername 'RemoteComputer' { #readregistrycodehere }` could be what you're looking for. You can read the Registry with `Get-ItemProperty`. This needs a configured WinRM Service

Answer (score 0):

There is no command-line tool for performing what you're wanting to do.  However, you can write a small script/application that can do this.  It would:

1. Mount all of the user registry hives
2. Search for each HKU mounted hive for the key
3. Unmount all of the hives

Mounting hives takes Administrator rights...